# Command line Octave undefined functions

Tags: signal-processing, octave

I am trying to run Octave from the command line. The Octave function uses some functions that are signal processing related (e.g. padarray).

The function version (when run from Octave) runs with no problem. When I run from the command line with the following code, I get the error 'padarray' undefined. How do I get this function to be included?

Here's a simple example of the difference between two pieces of code.

Function

```
function [] = pad_function()
    vec = ones(2,1);
    vec = pad_vector(vec);
end

function padded_vector = pad_vector(vec)
    padded_vector = padarray(vec,2);   
endfunction
```

Script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/octave -qf
function padded_vector = pad_vector(vec)
    padded_vector = padarray(vec,100);

endfunction

vec = ones(2,1);
vec = pad_vector(vec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the -f flag in the shebang line removes this error.

The -f flag causes Octave to not read from the initialization file, which I suppose links to the locations of these signal processing functions.

Comment: you are doing it wrong. The `-f` means that it won't run any of the local configuration stuff which is very important or you may be running it on a modified system. You want to have the `-f` on the shebang line. What you should do is add `pkg load image` (padarray is part of the image package) at the top of your script (just like you would do `import image` in python, `use image` in perl, or `#include <image.h>` in C++).